# Useless alone, but deadly in numbers

Tags: riddle

A nice riddle my friend Nathan made:

> Useless alone,
>   but deadly in numbers.
>   I am at the heart of connection.
>   Me and my friends are at the root of modern society.
>   Though indivisibly small,
>   We operate your second brain,
>   Humanity's hive mind.

What am I?

Hint #1:

> Think indivisibly small

Hint #2:

> I really do mean deadly in numbers

If you choose to downvote please comment with a reason below so I may improve/fix the problem.

Comment: Is connection intentionally misspelled?

Comment: This can turn into too broad. You can edit and add few more lines to it.

Comment: may be it's a  nucleus

Comment: I'm starting to get a mitochondria vibe from the extra lines and bonuses lol.. Those who played parasite eve will know what I'm talking about.

Comment: An ryrpgeba(rot13) is divisible though

Comment: I was going to write an answer about bees but the first hint :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My second guess after the edits in question and hints

Are you an

> Electron?

Useless alone,

> electron is useless if alone. But electricity is the collection of electrons.

but deadly in numbers.

> Electrocution

I am at the heart of connection.

> Electron (electricity) is the heart of all connections

Me and my friends are at the root of modern society.

> Electrons/Electricity is the root of modern society

Though indivisibly small,

> Electron is indivisibly small.

We operate your second brain,

> Computers and computational devices

Humanity's hive mind.

> Networking

---

Are you a

> Mobile Phone

Useless alone,

> Mobile phone is useless alone. We can contact or keep in touch with others only if they too have one.

but deadly in numbers.

> There are billions of mobile phones

I am at the heart of connection.

> Mobiles are the heart of connection (social media, chat etc)

Me and my friends are at the root of modern society.

> Mobiles are a must in the modern society.

We operate your second brain,

> Nowadays mobile phones has so many features that we can even call it as our second brain.

Humanity's hive mind.

> We can store and record everything in it.

Comment: "Indivisibly small"

Comment: Ive updated the riddle and added some hints, check them out and try again please.

Comment: Answer updated, Please check.

Comment: Bingo, indivisibly small, something others have missed.

Comment: Oh. I updated as Neuron. :D anyway +1

Comment: At first I thought it would be nucleus. (heart of connection, root, brain etc remind me of it) :P

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A computer?

Useless alone, but deadly in numbers.

> A computer by itself is not much, but when it is connected on a network or the internet with all the other computers of the planet it really shines!
>  Deadly in numbers could also refer to a dos attack from computer "zombies" for the tech savvy out there.

I am at the heart of connection.

> Connects everyone through the internet.

Me and my friends are at the root of modern society.

> Computers and information technology is what drives all the recent advancement in technology.

We operate your second brain, Humanity's hive mind.

> Google is pretty much like a second brain to me. The hive mind refer to how our knowledge is all shared between us and seems like we think as a collective... Like the Borgs(for those who understands the reference :P)

Comment: "Indivisibly small"

Comment: Ive updated the riddle and added some hints, check them out and try again please.

Comment: Are computers useless alone though? Just some thought.

Comment: "A computer by itself is not much" - really..?

Answer (score 1):

Question may be too broad at the moment. So another answer -

Previous Answer

> Zero.

**Updated**

Is it

> Neuron

Useless alone,

> Obvio.

but deadly in numbers.

> All the calculations are done using neurons.

I am at the heart of connection.

> Neurons help brain to communicate with other body parts.

Me and my friends are at the root of modern society.

> Neuro Science and other studies

Though indivisibly small, We operate your second brain,
Humanity's hive mind.

> They reside in Cerebellum at the back. Hence second brain

Comment: Ive updated the riddle and added some hints, check them out and try again please.

Comment: @ThatAmateurRiddler- Updated

Answer (score 0):

Edit: too slow haha

It is

> an electron.

Useless alone,
but deadly in numbers.

> because electric shocks.

I am at the heart of connection.
Me and my friends are at the root of modern society.

> Electricity is essential for modern society and its means of communication.

Though indivisibly small,

> Electrons are indivisible.

We operate your second brain,

> That would be the computer.

Humanity's hive mind.

> Or the Internet, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Ray of light

?
Makes sense doesn't it?

though indivisibly small

> its thickness cannot be measured on a ruler.

Useless alone

> one ray of light is barely visible

Deadly in numbers

> flashbang!!!

Hive mind

> human receives >95% of data through rays of light.

For the rest lines

> I am everywhere!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Bacteria

Because

> Bacteria operate your second brain (your gut), are invisibly small and deadly in large numbers (as in an infection).

Furthermore,

> Bacteria are crucial components in a lot of process and could therefore be regarded as a fabric of (modern) society.

Comment: I do not know how to edit it, so it only become visible when someone hoovers with the pointer.

Comment: What 'second brain'?

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @Mithrandir, the  second brain is one's gut (see [this article] (https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/gut-second-brain/)